# Pointwise limit of a sequence of functions when the domain depends on $n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am struggling to prove the pointwise limit of a function which has a domain which depends on $n$, specifically $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n^2x, \; x \in [0, 1/n]\\
2n - n^2x, \; x \in [1/n, 2/n]\\
0, \; x \in [2/n, 2]
 \end{cases}$$

I can see intuitively that the pointwise limit is the zero function, however the domain dependence on $n$ is confusing me in the proof.

Comment: The domain of all functions is $[0, 2]$, it  does not depend on $n$.

Comment: I understand this, what I mean is that if we look at $x \in (0,1/n]$ for example, then the interval is going to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, but there will always be a point in that interval where the function gets arbitrarily large because of the $n^2$.

Comment: In order to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ you consider a *fixed* $x$ and look what happens for large $n$. Hint: Consider the cases $x= 0$ and $0 < x \le 2$ separately.

Comment: No. If $n > 2/x$ then $f_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: Ok if $x \in (0, 1/n]$, then for small enough $n$ the definition of $f_n(x)$ says that $f_n(x) = n^2 x$, but for $n$ large enough $x$ wont be in $(0,1/n]$ as this gets smaller and smaller, so $x$ will be contained in $[2/n, 2]$. Is this the idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions $f_n$ are defined on the same domain $[0, 2]$. But each function is a [piecewise-defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) and the subintervals of the piecewise definition depends on $n$.

It is correct (as you said in a comment) that the functions $f_n$ can take arbitrarily large values for large $n$: We have $f_n(1/n) = n$. But this is irrelevant if we consider *pointwise* convergence.

For pointwise convergence we fix an argument $x \in [0, 2]$ and study the behavior of $f_n(x)$ for $n \to \infty$. Here it is convenient to treat the cases $x = 0$ and $x > 0$ separately.

If $x = 0$ then $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$, so
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(0) = 0 \, .
$$
If $0 < x \le 2$ then $f_n(x)$ depends on $n$ in the following way:
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
 n^2x     & \text{ if } n \le 1/x \, ,\\
2n - n^2x &  \text{ if } 1/x \le n \le 1/x \, , \\
0     &  \text{ if } n \ge 2/x \, .
 \end{cases}
$$
We see that $f_n(x) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0 \, .
$$

This proves that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0, 2]$, i.e. $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function.

As an exercise, I suggest that you prove that the convergence is not *uniform.*